# Copy string from Beginning to End part 2

Tags: c++

Okay This is what i have been battling with for sometime now and i have not been able to achieve results, How can i copy everything from beginning to end, Code looks like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iosteream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char name[50] = "Jason Statham";
    char *namesearch = strstr(name,"Jason"); // get position
    std::copy(name); //Copy Full Details concerning name From beginning to end. - problem
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (char*)name, "", MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do here. What behavior do you expect?

Comment: Many thanks @Logicrat , i am trying to find the position , i use strstr() or std::find() for that , in this case i use strstr() to get the position if it finds the name, Jason, it should copy everything there from the beginning of the string to the end, and show in a messagebox()

Answer (score 1):

For using [`copy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/) you first need to include `<algorithm>`.   Then you can do :

```
    if(namesearch) // make sure string was found
       std::copy(namesearch,  name+sizeof(name), name);
```

where `namesearch` is the start element to copy, `name+sizeof(name)` (or better `namesearch+strlen(namesearch)+1`) is the last element to copy, and `name` the destination.

In your example, you won't see anything special because "Jason" is already at the beginning.

**Edit:**

If you want to insert, you cant use `copy()`, but you have to use [`copy_backward()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_backward/):

```
    char *insertpoint = name + 5; // at the end of Jason
    char middle[] = " Donbell";
    std::copy_backward(insertpoint, insertpoint+strlen(insertpoint)+1, insertpoint+strlen(insertpoint)+1+strlen(middle));
    std::copy(middle, middle+strlen(middle), insertpoint);
```

But this code is only a proof of concept, because in any case you'd need to check that your inserting will not create a buffer overflow (i.e. `strlen(name)+1+strlen(middle)<sizeof(name)` )

So, if you intend to do a lot of string manipulation, I'd strongly advise that you have a look at `std::string()`.

Here how it would look like:

```
string nm = "xx Jason Statham";
auto ns = nm.find("Jason");   // find the start of "Jason"
if (ns!=std::string::npos) {  // if it was found....
   nm = nm.substr(ns);           // take a substring starting at the found position
   nm.insert(5, " Donbell");     // insert a string at poistion 5 
}                              // and all this without risk of buffer overflow !
```

Comment: What if i want to Add a Name like Donbell to it what do i do there to make it "Jason Donbell Statham" @Christophe

Comment: `and all this without risk of buffer overflow !` Ill buy 2!